# TwitterSourceConnector must be subclass of SourceConnector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Kafka Connect launching through `docker-compose` kafka-cluster with base from: `landoop/fast-data-dev:lastest`  where latest ends up being **Kafka Connect Version 2.6.2-LO**, also tried **2.6.2-LO**. Both failed to successfully create and run the connector.

When vieweing connector status: `http://localhost:8083/connectors/source-twitter-distributed/status`

I see the trace below which I cannot understand since the connector comes bundled:

```
{
    "name": "source-twitter-distributed",
    "connector": {
        "state": "FAILED",
        "worker_id": "127.0.0.1:8083",
        "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Connector implementations must 
be a subclass of either SourceConnector or SinkConnector
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.initialize(WorkerConnector.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:131)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:117)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n"
    },
    "tasks": [],
    "type": "unknown"
}
```

Any insights?

Comment: Have you tried using standalone Kafka Connect outside of Docker?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, haven't tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Wont select this as the official answer, but I believe it could be more related to landoop versions vs Connector.

Ended up changing `landoop/fast-data-dev:latest` to `lensesio/fast-data-dev:2.5.1-L1`, re-created all and now the connection and data is flowing as expected.